# How to analyze multiple distributions with groupby in pandas efficiently

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, distribution, pandas-groupby

Given a data frame like this :

```
Group Feature 
A     0.1
B     0.8
A     0.2
A     0.2
B     0.3
...
```

I want to analyze each distribution of Feature for each group and relate them to each other. The goal is to obtain the distributions of the random variables mean, median, skewness and quantiles of the mean, median, skewness and quantiles of the individual distributions.

Also i want to plot the distributions, while highlighting the mean and e.g. the distribution of the 0.25 und 0.75 percentiles.

Example plot:

[image]

My first idea is to compute a new data frame like:

```
Group Mean Median Skewness 0.1Percentile 0.2Percentile .....
A     0.2  0.2    0.3      0.01          0.02
C     0.3  0.2    1.2      0.05          0.06
...
```

Than one could plot each row and print the statistics for the distributions of the columns.

But this seems very clumsy to me.  How can this be performed smarter? Can this be performed similar to an approach for bootstrapping/resampling?

Comment: With df.describe() you can get statistical summary for each column.

Comment: Yeah. As i said with describe and groupby i could stich together the second dataframe as shown below. However, to me this seems to must be possible in a more automated fashion

Comment: What's more automated than `df.groupby('Group').describe()`?